# Extracting column from numpy array - unhashable array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a file of experimental data that I have parsed into a numpy array. I am attempting to extract the first column of the array into a variable using:

```
Thermo_Col = df[:,[0]]
```

where `Thermo_Col` is the column of temperatures and df is the numpy array

and I get an error

```
TypeError: unhashable type
```

Help

Answer (score 0):

I think df is not a numpy array, but a DataFrame, try this:

```
df.iloc[:, [0]]
```

Comment: Correct solution - didn't realize that a dataframe was different from an array even though it is "array like"